# how to programmatically enable Location service for my application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-location

how to programmatically enable Location service for my application on iPhone.
I don't want the warning window to show up and ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not allow to use user location without his agree. And the window is presented by the os. So if you want to do this you have to use private apis and your app will be rejected from the store.

Answer (score 0):

Like Terente says, you can't do this if you want to distribute your app through the app store.

If you aren't trying to do that, take a look at how KIF does it.  The relevant code is in the _enableAccessibility method, at https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/blob/master/Classes/KIFTestActor.m#L47